# Robotiq gripper gazebo model

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I found in industrial stack/package a ROBOTIQ urdf model, but without a Gazebo description. Is such description exist? how can I create one?

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110156/robotiq-gripper-gazebo-model/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

We were in need of this model as well and started converting it to gazebo ourselves.
You can do it yourself, following this tutorial:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_A_URDF_In_Gazebo

Basically, you need to add  tags to all links. You need a little knowledge on urdf and xacro:
http://wiki.ros.org/xacro

---

Originally posted by [sep300](https://answers.ros.org/users/11656/sep300/) with karma: 61 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-02-06**:
You'll also want to represent the finger's underactuation somehow. A Gazebo plugin would be an option. You would have to determine the efforts for each finger phalanx based on their current state, the actuator effort, and the contact forces.

**Comment by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on 2014-09-19**:
Have you managed to convert it to gazebo?